# ¿Cómo cambiar una fecha MySQL al formato "dd/MM/yyy"?

Tags: java, mysql

Yo no sé como escribir el código correctamente.

Les dejo un ejemplo para que pedan ayudarme.

En MySQL la fecha esta grabada en formato "yyyy/MM/dd".

```
My Bean

public class ClienteBean {
    private Date dataAbertura;

}

    public Date getDataAbertura() {
        return dataAbertura;
    }

    public void setDataAbertura(Date dataAbertura) {
        this.dataAbertura = dataAbertura;
    }    

My Dao

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
private ResultSet rs;


public class ClienteDAOImpl implements ClienteDAO {

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
.
.
.
cliente.setTelefono(rs.getString("cli_telefono"))
cliente.setDataAbetura(df.format(rs.getDate("cli_data_abertura")));

return cliente;

}
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el formato de fecha en la base de datos es `yyyy/MM/dd` ¿es un tipo de campo texto, `DATE` o `DATETIME`?

Comment: No entiendo en realidad cuál es el problema o error en tu código. Si fuera tú, no aplicaría un formato usando un *setter*, tratándose de un miembro de una clase del tipo fecha. ¿Por qué?  porque lo despojo de su versatilidad, por ejemplo en el caso de que se necesite ese miembro para distintas representaciones: `dd-mm-yyyy` o `dd de MMMM de YYYY`, etc. Donde tienes que aplicar formato es allí donde vayas a imprimir el dato, pues es ahí donde se requiere ese formato en específico. Ten en cuenta que un formato es solamente una representación de los datos, setearlos formateados es sacrificarlos.

Answer (score 0):

El método `setDataAbertura` recibe parámetros del tipo `Date`, por lo que la linea en la que le pasas los datos debería ser así:

```
cliente.setDataAbetura(rs.getDate("cli_data_abertura"));
```

y solo le aplicas el formato cuando quieres mostrar los datos, como por ejemplo:

```
Textfield.setText(df.format(cliente.getDataAbertura()));
```

o si es por consola, de esta forma:

```
System.out.println(df.format(cliente.getDataAbertura()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dando por hecho que el tipo de cli_data_abertura en base de datos es DATE:

```
private LocalDate cliDataAbertura;

//leer valor desde BD
cliDataAbertura = rs.getDate("cli_data_abertura").toLocalDate();//si no puede ser nulo en BD
cliDataAbertura = rs.getDate("cli_data_abertura")!= null ? rs.getDate("cli_data_abertura").toLocalDate() : null;//si puede ser nulo en BD

//Mostrar valor en pantalla con formato dd-mm-yyy
DateTimeFormatter formateadorFecha = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyy")
String cliDataAberturaComoString = cliDataAbertura.format(formateadorFecha );

//Guardar en BD
st.setDate(cliDataAbertura!=null ? Date.valueOf(cliDataAbertura) : null;
```

Comment: Pablo,
gracias por la contesta. He me equivocado con una información.
En el MYsql el formato es = "yyyy-MM-dd".

En My Dao - estoy con una class <list> para exhibir en el grid, por exemplo:

Telefono   - Data abertura
12345678 - 15/03/2019

Tengo otras celdas  de fecha em mi tabla exhibir en mi relatorio.

¿Cómo debo hacer ?

Gracias,
desde Brasil(José Bonfim)

Comment: El formato en BD debería dar igual a la hora de guardar/leer el valor. Si quieres mostrar en pantalla con diferentes formatos, lo único que tienes que hacer es cambiar el formato de formateadorFecha.